# Upload images with Uservoice

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading, voting, uservoice

I think I'm going to go with UserVoice for a free user voting service, because they are the only one I've found that offer an API (which is a requirement for me, because I need to be able to create a custom UI).

But it looks like the user can't upload an image with their suggestion - just text only.

I need users to be able to upload their description AND an image to go with it.

So I will roll my own image upload with DB solution, and tie image id's to the suggestion id's generated by UserVoice...

Unless there's a better way?

- Another free voting service with API AND image upload?
- An upload feature for UserVoice which I overlooked somehow?
- A preexisting other 3rd party library specifically for adding image upload feature to UserVoice?

Comment: Uploading the image is only available on paid plans. `Image uploads are available on all paid plans.`. See this: http://feedback.uservoice.com/forums/1-general-feedback/suggestions/2764526-upload-and-host-embedded-images-within-uservoice

Comment: Submit your solution as an answer. If no one else submits a better one, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on the site, uploading the image is only available on paid plans. The site quotes it as `Image uploads are available on all paid plans.`

See this link: http://feedback.uservoice.com/forums/1-general-feedback/suggestions/2764526-upload-and-host-embedded-images-within-uservoice